# DataList is not loading in my aspx page from my webusercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a web user Control that looks like this

.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HtmlReport.ascx.cs" Inherits="HtmlReport" %>
```

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="REPORT DATALST" />
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataListNames">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /><p>, </p>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataListHours">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HoursWorked") %>' />
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Total Hours " /><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalHoursWorked") %>' />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

.cs

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void GenerateReport(IList<DataObjects.Fixedfeereport> FixedFeeReports)
    {
        DataListNames = new DataList();
        DataListNames.DataSource = FixedFeeReports;
        DataListNames.DataBind();
    }
```

and in my contentpage .cs

```
                HtmlReport rpt = new HtmlReport();
            rpt.GenerateReport(Reports);
    //Reports is a data object that holds all the fields from the webusercontrol datalist, ex: CustomerName, ProjectName, FirstName, LastName, etc....

            Control test = Page.LoadControl("HtmlReport.ascx");
            PanelReport.Controls.Add(test);
```

My issue is, when I load my webuserControl onto my original contentpage lets call it default.aspx / default.cs, it grabs the Label which I have "REPORT DATALIST", and it displays that - cool. But, it grabs the datalist, and it is empty. Contains no data, even though I am giving it a datasource and databinding it in the .cs

I haven't worked with webusercontrols like this before so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue, I actually moved the webusercontrol onto the aspx page from the solution explorer, dragged and dropped it. Which Gave me this at the Top of my default.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/HtmlReport.ascx" TagName="Report" TagPrefix="R"  %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/HtmlReport.ascx" %>
```

and this in my Panel I dropped it in.

```
<R:Report ID="Report1" runat="server" />
```

i changed my contentpage.cs to look like this,

```
Report1.GenerateReport(Reports);
```

and finally I removed the

```
DataListNames = new Datalist();
```

in my webusercontrol.cs, and it works and renders my datalist!